# Net Core - получение entityId:guid из route контроллера

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Имеется контроллер TestController с роутом:

```
Route("v0/entities/{entityId:guid}/elements")]
```

Имеется ендпоинт:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("create")]
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Object command)
{
  //...
}
```

Соответственно, пример вызова ендпоинта:

```
POST https://localhost:pppp/v0/entities/1A1F0371-2916-4AA8-B173-D329534FC45A/elements/create
```

Вопрос: Я правильно понимаю, изъятие entityId на бек-енде нужно реализовать в контрукторе контроллера (сделать entityId параметром конструктора), а не в конкретном ендпоинте? Или entityId нужно передавать в каждый ендпоинт контроллера? Простите, я не понимаю.

Спасибо

Comment: Я конечно могу ошибаться, но вроде бы через конструктор это не делается. Вот тут исчерпывающая информация https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @ПавелПопов Да, Вы правы. Я тоже нашел эту ссылку. Спасибо за помощь, я разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

В моем случае **entityId:guid** будет как входящий параметр в конкретный ендпоинт, все оказалось значительно проще.